# use outputcache or session variable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, outputcache

Im using asp.net mvc 3.

Im implementing a points system similar to SO. I want to show the users points on every page. should i store this in a session variable?

or can i use outputcache on a partial action to show it on every page?
i dont want to make a dbcall just for this on every page.

im a little reluctan with session variable, i hear too many mixed comments about them

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't store it in session.

If the user does something that affects their points, you'll have to update the session each time. Use session for things that change rarely during a user's time on your website (like their username, preferences, etc).

Don't forget, what if someone "upvotes" something the user has done - how would you know about this unless you call the db?

I would use regular `Cache`, possibly with a `SqlCacheDependency` on the table which contains the user rep, so when it changes it invalidates the cached data.

Comment: the thing is im not so bothered about the points being exactly acurate. they can be updated every 24hours. similar to SO where yours reutation isnt instantly updated.

Comment: @raklos, actually, SO is updated immediately. like when you accept an answers, immediately you get 2 rep points. Im not sure how stack does it, i think they'd use some kind of caching, otherwise their db servers would get smashed. but if you don't want the rep updated immediately, just use output cache - vary by the user, expiry 24 hours.